# Entity Framework does not keep JSON data Id

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, especially Entity Framework.

I am trying to save JSON data from external service to SQL server. I use Code First and it creates tables and inserts all records. But original ID values are changed to SQL auto generated ID value. For example, original ID 20050 become 1. Please check attached photos. I googled my problem and did not find a solution.

This is my fist time posting a question in stackoverflow too. Thanks in Advance.

[image: ID value in JSON Data, in Visual Studio]

[image: ID value in Table, In SQL Server]

Comment: It looks like you're using the model class from the TMDB library as your model. This is possible (You can use the [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591617.aspx#1.1) to define your key) but is generally a bad idea. Your entities that are stored in the database should be "POCO"s (Plain Old CLR Objects - basically classes with nothing but properties / annotations). I'd suggest you make a model class of your own and use that

Comment: Thanks Basic, I tried Fluent Api and it works. I gonna learn how to use my own model and HTTP Client too.

Answer (score 0):

you can set identity specification to false to that table usine `DataAnnotations` attribute.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)];
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

Than apply migration.

Comment: I tried to change identity Specification. But, saving change is not permitted. The message said "The changes you have made require the table to be dropped and re-created." Any other way?

Comment: Also, if you're doing code-first, this is not the right approach. You'd have to go and update your database every time it's (re)created

Comment: @Basic: i have changes my answer.

Comment: Thanks Amit, I use DataAnnotations in Fluent API and it works.

Comment: Hi Amit, I will do it when I can. I need 15 reputations to do it.

Comment: @you don't need 15 reputation to accept answer. Min 15 reputation is required for Upvote.